# El "else" me marca un error. "El término de la expresión 'else' no es válido"

Tags: c#, condiciones

El ultimo else me marca un error, no se cual es el error si ya cerré las llaves.
Lo que estoy programando es que hay que ingresar un numero de 3 cifras y determinar si el primer numero es igual al ultimo

```
            int num, dig1 = 0, dig2 = 0, dig3 = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero de 3 digitos");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (num >= 100 && num <= 999)
            dig1 = num / 100;
            dig2 = num % 100 / 10;
            dig3 = num % 10;
        {
            if (dig1 == dig3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El primer numero es igual al ultimo");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El primer numero no es igual al ultimo");
                }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero de tres digitos");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Estan todos mal los corchetes ahi.. que tratabas de hacer????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien te dice @gbianchi, vigila en tema de los corchetes

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num, dig1 = 0, dig2 = 0, dig3 = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero de 3 digitos");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (num >= 100 && num <= 999)
        {
            dig1 = num / 100;
            dig2 = num % 100 / 10;
            dig3 = num % 10;

            if (dig1 == dig3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El primer numero es igual al ultimo");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El primer numero no es igual al ultimo");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero de tres digitos");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Deberia haber sido cerrada por error tipografico ;/

Comment: Muchas gracias por resolverme el error

Comment: La verdad, desconocía el tema del error tipográfico. Acabo de entrar en publicaciones de Meta y ya he leído sobre ello.